# Google Maps API V2: How to add markers which behave like the default google maps markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I was wondering, with the free version... Can I plot the more default markers (from maps.google.com). The kind which when clicked, offer the option to enter driving directions and other tid-bits pulled from google's search of a business (eg: reviews).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options like driving directions can be achieved by adding links to the infowindow that call the part of your code that does GDirections calls.

If you've got some reviews, then the Maps API provides you with the tools necessary to display them in the infowindow.

You need to code each of the other tid-bits you want individually. Almost all of them can be achieved with sufficient effort, but there's no shortcut. Be warned. Google are consstantly improving maps.google.com. If you get your site to work exactly like maps.google.com today, you may well find that when you look again a few months later, there are significant differences.

If you want something that does the whole lot exactly like Google, then you might consider using Google Maps itself, or an embedded Google Map, rather than using the API.